# C# What is the best way to create an enum that is used by multiple classes?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum which is used by multiple classes. What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Put the enums right in your namespace (or make a new namespace for them)
   or
2. Put them in a (static?) class somewhere if that makes more sense.

I'd keep them in their own file for easy access and good organization either way.

I usually wouldn't put them in a class unless they somehow "belong" there. Like you have a Car class with an enum for the types of car, and a Road class and Bridge class that can set limits for types of car. `Car.CarType` seems to be a logical organization for this...

Comment: How do i put an enum in my namespace? How do i create such a file?

Comment: Create a new .cs file with: namespace MyNameSpace { public enum MyEnum {Value1, Value2, Value3} }

Comment: It's not a class just an enum in a namespace.

Comment: Enums don't have to be in a class. They CAN be, but don't have to be. Note Killersponge's response about following MS's lead as well.

Comment: I don't get it. I have an cs file as you suggested. But when i type myEnum. i don't get the intellisense list with enum values and myEnum is declared public.

Comment: If the namespace the enum is in is different from the namespace you're in, you need to "using" the enum's namespace.

Answer (score 13):

Typically I just throw them into the namespace. It's what Microsoft did writing the .NET framework, so it's what I do too, for consistency you understand :)

Comment: nice, i didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 9):

XML comments help, especially if others will use it

```
 /// <summary>
/// Defines the types of cars we support
/// </summary>
public enum CarType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// VW - the peoples car
    /// </summary>
    Volkswagen,
```

Your enum name should be plural (as instructed by FxCop)

```
public enum CarTypes
```

Add numeric values and use bitwise numbering even if you don't plan to use bitwise (it's a pain to renumber later).

```
    Volkswagen = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// They own lambo... can't be all that bad
    /// </summary>
    Audi = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// Good, cheap, reliable
    /// </summary>
    Toyota = 4,
```

Answer (score 8):

Put it in its own file and just declare it:

public enum Foo { a, b, c, d }

Consider your namespacing of course.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of having two enums in different namespaces:

```
using TotallyDifferentNameSpace.Enums;

namespace EnumEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CarType car = CarType.Audi;
            PetrolType pType = PetrolType.Diesel;
        }
    }

    public enum CarType
    {
        Volkswagen,
        Audi,
        Toyota,
        Ford,
        Porsche,
        Lada
    }
}

namespace TotallyDifferentNameSpace.Enums
{
    public enum PetrolType
    {
        Gasoline,
        Diesel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put an enum is a new codefile with .cs extension, for intellisense to work make sure its part of your project/solution and ofcourse it should be a public enum so that you have a solution scope for it. If intellisense is a problem , make sure you build your solution once, i had this problem once and just a rebuild solved it. Namespacing is a good option if you want to organize your code properly and you are coding a large project. The .NET framework was large. so it has enums under namespaces just for better understanding and code organization.

Answer (score -9):

My advice is to not use Enums at all. Use singletons instead.

Like

```
    public class A : ISomeInterface
    {
        public static readonly A Instance = new A();
        private A()
        {
        }

    }

    public class B : ISomeInterface
    {
        public static readonly B Instance = new A();
        private B()
        {
        }
    }
```

In most cases that works better and is better to extend later.

Best wishes

Matze

Comment: This is somewhat similar to the type safe enum pattern, but its overengineering for no reason. Stay agile, refactor your enums later if its needed.

Comment: Trouble starts if you need to extend your Enums later. One new value for customer A, another one for customer B. Boom! Ups! Both mapped to same int.

Of course if you are 100% sure the Enum will never be changed ..

Comment: If you think the enums will change, you shouldn't use enumerations. Use classes instead.